# How to create SSL certificate with Unicode characters in the Organization name (or other fields)?

Tags: ssl, unicode, certificate

I've created a self-signed SSL certificate and have no trouble using it, but the browser (Firefox, Chrome/IE) shows garbled characters in the Organization's name (anything above ASCII has 2 characters).

I created the certificate in a Debian running on virtualbox (Win host), the shell's locales are all *.UTF-8, and I used CA.pl for this. I can create files with Unicode characters and have no other issues, but the cert has "OrganizauÃ§Ã£o" instead of "Organização".

Any tips? Escaping the characters (how)? Dumbing down the locale to  ISO/IEC 8859-1? Using some non-shell method? Am i missing something obvious?

On a side note, is there an easy way (i.e. 4ummies™) to distribute the certificate, so a user can just click and install? All the guides i've seen involve too many windows for a regular user to bother with; and without installing it the browser will yelp every time the user visits (except Firefox which allows an easy installation via the warning box).

**Edit 1**

Checking the asn1parse manpage and using its example:

```
openssl asn1parse -genstr 'UTF8:Organização'
```

produces:

```
0:d=0  hl=2 l=  17 prim: UTF8STRING        :OrganizaÃ§Ã£o
```

So i assume it's a problem with the input. This is my locale information:

```
LANG=pt_PT.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
All LC_* fields="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

I have no problems touching Organização or any other files with nonASCII characters, yet my CA cert gets dumbed down to 8bits.

**Edit 2**

I've started with [this](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/618/Certificate_Authority_CA_with_OpenSSL) tutorial, but went on to reading the OpenSSL man. In reading the `req` man i came across [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#BUGS) in the bugs section: *As a consequence of the T61String handling the only correct way to represent accented characters in OpenSSL is to use a BMPString*

So i tried with:

```
openssl asn1parse -genstr 'BMP:Organização'
```

and end up with an empty string:

```
0:d=0  hl=2 l=  26 prim: BMPSTRING
```

Comment: I checked a bunch of sites: the majority has their heads in the ASCII sands, but some do use non-ASCII characters, so it's not a protocol limitation or something.

Comment: According to [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), `organizationName` allowed types are `teletexString`, `printableString`, `universalString`, `utf8String ` and `bmpString`. `openssl.cnf` uses `string_mask = utf8only` by default. Did you perform an ASN.1 dump on the cert to ensure its *not* UTF8 (see `openssl asn1parse -in ...` and [asn1parse(1)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/asn1parse.html))? What are you using to display the cert and `organizationName`?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/), [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, @jww, i've edited the question. I'm using the browser: viewing the certificate information when it complains it's not trusted. I've tried portuguese and english firefox+win7, as well as chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Followed [another](https://wiki.debian.org/Self-Signed_Certificate) tutorial and adapted the certificate creation to:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -utf8 -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem
```

I opted to populate the default config file with the answers to the questions (instead of supplying them via the prompt) and added a commented non-ASCII character just to make sure it's a unicode file (kinda unnecessary i guess but `file` made me happy by saying *UTF-8 Unicode text*).

Comment: this was not enough, it worked for me when i added `-nameopt multiline,utf8` in addition to `-utf8` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478452/how-to-create-csr-with-utf8-subject-in-openssl#29649477

Answer (score 2):

Decode the string into escaped-ASCII and specify on the command line. For the *Univeristät Innsbruck*, the umlaut-a must be translated into ASCII bytes. The Unicode tables show that it is U+00E4 which must be represented by the hex character sequence `c3` `a4`. To get that on the command-line, I do:

```
server=test.uibk.ac.at
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout $server.key -out $server.csr \
-subj '/C=AT/ST=Tyrol/L=Innsbruck/O=Universit\\xC3\\xA4t Innsbruck/OU=IT Services/CN='"$server"
```

Note, the double-backslashes and *single quotes* are both required. To test the effect:

```
openssl x509 -in test.uibk.ac.at.crt -noout -text |grep Subject:
```

we see

```
Subject: C=AT, ST=Tyrol, L=Innsbruck, O=Universit\xC3\xA4t Innsbruck, OU=IT Services, CN=test.uibk.ac.at
```

In the browser, we verify the key and see "Universität Innsbruck" as expected.

Comment: So what's the point of this escaping? Can't Linux display Unicode characters?
What if I want to get the original `Universität Innsbruck` value in shell by parsing the certificate - how do I do that?

Comment: OK, this worked for me: `-nameopt lname,sep_multiline,utf8`