# openssl req utf8 strings

Tags: utf-8, openssl, distinguishedname

as others i'm struggling with utf8 in requests. sure i went through all preciding questions and answers. well here is my workout.
configuration:

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_md          = sha256
string_mask         = utf8only
utf8                = yes
distinguished_name  = DistName
attributes          = Attr

[ DistName ]
commonName          = Name (your official name)
commonName_default  = hans nägli dödüé
stateOrProvinceName = State or Province Name (full name)
countryName         = Country Code (2 letter code)
countryName_default = CH

[ Attr ]
subjectAltName      = Name (international / latin)
subjectAltName_default  = hans nägeli dädü
postalCode          = zip code
localityName        = Locality Name (eg, city)
emailAddress        = Email Address
```

i verified this config file is utf8 and started thereafter using default values:

```
openssl req -verbose -config CsrPerson.cfg -new -key HansMuster-ecpem.key -passin pass:gugus -out HansMuster-pem.csr
```

i then had a look into the request using

```
openssl req -utf8 -noout -text -in HansMuster-pem.csr
```

showing

```
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: CN = hans n\C3\A4gli d\C3\B6d\C3\BC\C3\A9, ST = z\C3\BCrich, C = CH
        Subject Public Key Info:
        ...snip...
                NIST CURVE: P-384
        Attributes:
            postalCode               :2222
            localityName             :Dörrhausen
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:hans nägeli dädü
            emailAddress             :hans.naegeli@gmx.net
        ...snip...
```

using same source, same configuration, same procedure: subject/distinguished name has not been treated as utf8 but worked out well with attributes even with locality name which was entred by keyboard.

ASN1 definition of subject show a possible content as utf8 string. openssl version OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017.

where have i been mistaken?
have fun

Comment: Same problem here - the same day :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

> openssl req -nameopt utf8 -noout -text -in HansMuster-pem.csr

This should only fix the display problem, you have to check if your other requirements are still met.

You can find more details about the "-nameopt" options here in the "NAME OPTIONS" section: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/x509.html

**Other related links:**

- [How to create CSR with utf8 subject in openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478452/how-to-create-csr-with-utf8-subject-in-openssl)